# Python class attribute assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, pass-by-reference

I'm new to Python, and I was wondering why I can't change the attribute for a class instance using a function, if I pass the instance as a function parameter
For example, if I had:

```
class sol:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 0

def fun1(obj, attrib):
    obj[attrib] = 1

newSol = sol()

fun1(newSol, "val")
```

Why can't fun1 change the object attribute? Is there a way to change it, or is the "val" attribute immutable?

Comment: Attribute access (`obj.attr`) and indexing (`obj[index]`) are entirely separate concepts in Python.  You'd need to use `setattr(obj, attrib, 1)` to set an attribute indirectly.

Comment: Sorry, in my mind I was thinking of dicts as objects, and I was assuming the same syntax for setting dict attributes was the same as setting object attribute. Would the sytax dict[attrib] = 1 work for dicts only then?

Comment: You can make your own class that supports indexing by implementing the `__setitem__()`/`__getitem__()` methods.

Comment: @albert `dict`s *are* objects. Everything in Python is an object. Dict objects cannot have attributes, and using `mydict[k] = v` does not create an attribute on the dict objects.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga what I meant to say was I was thinking of all objects in Python as dicts. And I'm a little confused about what you said about dicts. Using mydict[k] = v does create a k attribute for mydict, does it not?

Comment: @albert no, it does not. It assigns a key to a value, but these are not attributes

Comment: Hint: where the code says `self.val = 0`, why does it (correctly) **not** say `self['val'] = 0`? What do you think would happen if you tried that? What does happen if you do try it? Did you try *reading* the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python class instances and `dict` are completely different beasts; you're likely coming from a JavaScript background where `obj.foo` is equivalent to `obj["foo"]`, but that's not how Python works.

If you want to set an attribute via a `str` name, [use `setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
def fun1(obj, attrib):
    setattr(obj, attrib, 1)
```

Comment: Ah ok I was just wondering that. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: It seems a little disingenuous to suggest that there's *no* relation between object attributes and dictionaries, considering that most objects store their attributes in a `__dict__` dict.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh: Except when `__slots__` are involved, or it's a C built-in using descriptors to implement access, or when it's a subclass of `tuple` or `list` (e.g. anything made via `collections.namedtuple`) using `@property` to alias indices to names, etc. Yes, `__dict__` is implemented as a `dict`-like thing, often an actual `dict` (when it exists, which isn't always). But that's mostly an "in the weeds" implementation detail, and not relevant to how you *use* class instances in 99.999% of cases. Class instances don't quack like `dict`, so the relationship isn't relevant most of the time.